# Best way to distribute an iOS app without using the App store

Tags: ios

**The scenario:**
My company develops an iOS app for company A. Only employees of company A use this app and it must not appear in the Apple app store. Customer A pays us for developing the app, but the app itself is free.

**The problem:**
How do we distribute the app and updates to the employees (>100) of company A?

**How the perfect solution should look like:**
Like distribution through the app store: Company A doesn't need to do anything and the users can acquire/update the app easily and quickly.

**Notes**
Customer A wants to do as little as possible. They also don't really care about costs.

**My ideas so far, please let me know what you think about them**

1. My company applies for the iOS Enterprise Developer program (EDP) and puts the app on our own, login-protected website. Customer A doesn't need to do anything and its employees can simply download the app from the website.
2. Like 1., but customer A applies for the iOS EDP

The first method would be perfect, but according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323840/ios-enterprise-developer-program-how-would-apple-tell-random-customers-from-emp) it might be dangerous. Though I highly doubt Apple would press legal charges (Free app, relatively low number of users, companies located outside the USA), I really don't want to take that risk.

Therefore, I'm currently favoring the second method. It might be some effort for Customer A, but it's still convenient for the users and it doesn't violate the EULA as far as I can tell.

**My question:**
Are there other methods to distribute the app that make sense in this situation? 
Especially one that doesn't force our customers through a relatively complicated application process (most of them don't have a DUNS number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Here are some of them:

1)Fake code sign your app and jailbreak the devices you want to install it;

2)Create a web app instead of a native app;

3)Use Apple's B2B program;

4)Use enterprise distribution;

Comment: 1) isn't legal and is a lot of effort for company A. 2) Most companies don't like web apps. 3) B2B is only for companies in the US. 4) I agree.

Comment: Thank you Fernando for your suggestions. Although "Customer A" doesn't like the second suggestion, it might come in handy with other customers. I accepted your answer and will use the enterprise distribution for this customer.

Comment: Thank you dasdom for pointing out the problem with the B2B program (+1). It might be a viable solution for other SO users with a similar problem, but my Company and virtually all our customers are located in Europe.

Comment: Dasdom, jailbreak isn't ilegal in many countries. US for example.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion only your second approach is applicable. In my opinion the company should decide whether they want to have an app or not. And if they have enrolled the Enterprise Developer Program they can have as much app as they want.